# How to fix these cabal installation errors while installing diagrams?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-diagrams

I am trying to install the diagrams package written in haskell using Cabal. 
I get the following errors when I run `cabal install diagrams`

```
[~]$ cabal install diagrams
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
bytes-0.15.2 (via: linear-1.20.4) (reinstall) (changes: binary-0.8.2.1 -> 0.6.4.0)
linear-1.20.4 (via: diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8 force-layout-0.4.0.3 diagrams-lib-1.3.1.1 diagrams-core-1.3.0.6 active-0.2.0.8) (new package)
active-0.2.0.8 (via: diagrams-lib-1.3.1.1) (new package)
diagrams-core-1.3.0.6 (via: diagrams-1.3.0.1 diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8 diagrams-svg-1.4 diagrams-lib-1.3.1.1) (new package)
diagrams-lib-1.3.1.1 (via: diagrams-1.3.0.1 diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8 diagrams-svg-1.4) (new package)
diagrams-svg-1.4 (via: diagrams-1.3.0.1) (new package)
force-layout-0.4.0.3 (via: diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8) (new package)
diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8 (via: diagrams-1.3.0.1) (new package)
diagrams-1.3.0.1 (new package)
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/cabal-tmp-12921/bytes-0.15.2/dist/setup/setup.hs, /tmp/cabal-tmp-12921/bytes-0.15.2/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/cabal-tmp-12921/bytes-0.15.2/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring bytes-0.15.2...
Building bytes-0.15.2...
Preprocessing library bytes-0.15.2...
[1 of 5] Compiling Data.Bytes.Signed ( src/Data/Bytes/Signed.hs, dist/build/Data/Bytes/Signed.o )
[2 of 5] Compiling Data.Bytes.VarInt ( src/Data/Bytes/VarInt.hs, dist/build/Data/Bytes/VarInt.o )
[3 of 5] Compiling Data.Bytes.Put   ( src/Data/Bytes/Put.hs, dist/build/Data/Bytes/Put.o )
[4 of 5] Compiling Data.Bytes.Get   ( src/Data/Bytes/Get.hs, dist/build/Data/Bytes/Get.o )

src/Data/Bytes/Get.hs:205:15:
    Not in scope: `B.lookAhead'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `S.lookAhead' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAheadM' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAheadE' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get)

src/Data/Bytes/Get.hs:207:16:
    Not in scope: `B.lookAheadM'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `S.lookAheadM' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAhead' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAheadE' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get)

src/Data/Bytes/Get.hs:209:16:
    Not in scope: `B.lookAheadE'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `S.lookAheadE' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAhead' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get),
      `S.lookAheadM' (imported from Data.Serialize.Get)
Failed to install bytes-0.15.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
active-0.2.0.8 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
bytes-0.15.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
diagrams-1.3.0.1 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
diagrams-contrib-1.3.0.8 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
diagrams-core-1.3.0.6 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
diagrams-lib-1.3.1.1 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
diagrams-svg-1.4 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
force-layout-0.4.0.3 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
linear-1.20.4 depends on bytes-0.15.2 which failed to install.
```

I have installed bytes-0.15.2 separately with cabal using the command 
`cabal install bytes`. What could be going wrong? When installing diagrams cabal seems to be needlessly trying to install bytes again.

What can I do to fix these compilation errors?

I am running this on an Ubuntu 14.04 with ghc version 7.6.3 and cabal version 1.22.7.0

Comment: cabal-install is reinstalling bytes because it depends on binary; binary’s version is being changed from 0.8 to 0.6 because linear depends on binary<0.8. bytes is apparently misreporting its binary dependency because it’s using functions that aren’t present in 0.6. (Welcome to Haskell!) Try explicitly installing previous versions of bytes (0.15, 0.15.0.1, 0.15.1); since the maintainers of linear have set bytes>=0.15, it must not have always been broken.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Thank you for the response! Can you tell me how to do that? Do I need to modify my cabal command to install diagrams for this?

Comment: `cabal install bytes==0.15.1 diagrams` should do it.

Comment: You can also use stack to install diagrams; it's just `stack install diagrams`. Cabal-install is lovely in many ways, but it often breaks in the face of older packages with loose bounds. (If you do stick with cabal-install, I also recommend that you use a sandbox.) https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack

Comment: @RyanO'Hara Nope! Got the same error message with 0.15.1 in place of 0.15.2

Comment: @smilingbuddha: So try 0.15.0.1, then 0.15.

Comment: @haoformayor I think the underlying problem here is that the user is running ghc 7.6. Stackage isn't compat with that stuff -- the advantage for the user with stack would just be that it would install a more recent ghc...